# use function variable outside of the function WiTHOUT calling the function

Tags: php, string, function, global

I have a need for this. Is it possible?

I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$test;

function func_name() {
    global $test;
    $test = 'string';
}

echo $test; // I get nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't call the function, nothing will happen.

You need to add `func_name();` before `echo $test;`

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `global` instead pass arguments to your function. Also you are not returning the value from your function nor calling your function `func_name`.

You must be doing something like this.

```
<?php

function func_name() {   //<---- Removed the global keyword as it is a bad practice
    $test = 'string';
    return $test;   //<---- Added a retuen keyword
}
$test=func_name(); //<---- Calls your function and the value is returned here
echo $test; //"prints" string
```

Answer (score 0):

Can do like

```
function func_name() {
    $test = 'string';
    return $test;
} 
echo func_name();
```

Or even you can try like

```
function func_name() {
    $test = 'string';
    echo $test;
} 
func_name();
```

Comment: never use globals if it can be avoided.

Comment: @RonniSkansing I did'nt

Comment: using $this outside class wont work

Comment: @Gautam3164 Well I hope you a having some friday fun. Because editing a post an argumenting that you did not do it, makes no sense, it is in the edit history and no.. using $this in non object context makes no sense either...

Comment: Thanks @MarkS.I dnt knw exactly that it will.SO I even mention in ans also.Thnks for suggestion.I removed it

Comment: @RonniSkansing while copiyng from OP code I did but before your comment I have deleted it

Comment: @Gautam3164 now your code makes no sense again. why declare a variable named test inside the scope only to the return the value .

Comment: @RonniSkansing dont be harsh..As per OP I gave ans..May be he was getting that $test form other calculation.My ans makes global..there is no wrong with that

Comment: @Gautam3164 judging from you answers and edits I would think you either A) do not know php or B) are copying answers you do not understand. And yes there is something wrong with using globals.

Comment: @RonniSkansing finally ,It only a copr paste error and I edited it before your comment.that's it.We will stop this here.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48049/discussion-between-ronni-skansing-and-gautam3164)